# How to avoid timeout in Google Cloud Function for firebase user create handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have a google cloud function that gets triggered asynchronously when an user gets created (from Firebase SDK). Function gets executed, but it seems it doesn't resolve because it reaches the timeout and it produces an error on client side, and account doesn't get created.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.myFunction = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    console.log(user.uid);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(); });
});
```

On my client app (ReactJS) I get this as Cloud Function fails to resolve:

```
{code: "auth/internal-error", message: "Cloud function deadline exceeded.", a: null}
```

And on my cloud function logs I get this (thinking that, for some reason my code was taking too much, even increased the time to 360 seconds):

```
Function execution took 360002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

Why is the promise return not resolving the execution of my promise? I also tried by returning true or returning an integer, without success.

EDIT: Adding client-side code.

This is the code on client side (Using Firebase SDK). I'm not expecting a response from backend. If I remove the trigger in Firebase to the Cloud Function, user creation works fine (I get an object containing user info):

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.auth().tenantId = 'tenant-1'; //Using Google Identity provider
const response = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

Comment: Can you share the code from the client app (ReactJS) that "call" the function? It is not clear how you can get anything from your Cloud Function on the client, since it is a background triggered CF.

Comment: sure @RenaudTarnec , let me update my question. Just clarify that by not having the cloud function and its trigger, the same code that creates the user works fine. Not expecting to get anything from Cloud Function on client, just to trigger a background process (by invoking a REST API from there)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. Do you see the result of `console.log(user.uid);` in the <Cloud Function log (on the Firebase console)? I still don't understand what you mean by "On my client app (ReactJS) I get this as Cloud Function fails to resolve: `{code: "auth/internal-error", message: "Cloud function deadline exceeded.", a: null}`".

Comment: @RenaudTarnec use case is the following: I want to send an email on user creation (async). For that I need to use my own infrastructure (as firebase has an option for sending emails, but not customizable enough).
a) If I don't have the cloud function set up, and I create an user from my react app, everything goes fine (with the same frontend code)
b) If I link the cloud function, although cloud function is async, if it fails, it makes the user creation to fail, and I get the error message specified.
I'm not waiting any response on client side, only get user created successfully.

Comment: Even having the function body empty (removing the console.log, as I was just using them to see what it has), just returning a promise, or returning a 1 or returning true, cloud function fails, and frontend shows that error message "Cloud function deadline exceeded"